# Concatenation of a string in 'Character encryption function'

Tags: java, string, substring, concatenation

I am writing one function (out of four total) for an encryption program and I am having trouble concatenating the string together! I am new to java so go easy on me. I am open to suggestions and appreciate any help! I have searched the site to find an answer but couldn't find what I needed.

I am getting an error on my string concatenation: "int cannot be dereferenced"

I am using NetBeans IDE 8.1

Here is my pseudo-code:

For each character in the message,
Get the current character,
Convert the character into a two-character hexadecimal string,
Create a new character that consists of the concatenation of,
a random uppercase character + the first hex digit + a random digit,
a random uppercase character + the second hex digit + a random digit,
Concatenate this new character to the encrypted text you are going to return,

Here is what I have so far:

```
public static String EncryptCharacter(char character)
{
    Random generator = new Random();
    String encryptedCharacter;
    String letter = String.valueOf(character);
    int hexCharacter = (char)Integer.parseInt(letter,16);
    char randChar1 = (char)(61 + generator.nextInt(25));
    char randChar2 = (char)(61 + generator.nextInt(25));
    int randNum1 = generator.nextInt(10);
    int randNum2 = generator.nextInt(10);

    encryptedCharacter = (randChar1 + hexCharacter.substring(0,1) + randNum1    + randChar2 + hexCharacter.substring(1,2) + randNum2);

    return encryptedCharacter;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are casting your value as type `char` before setting assigning an `int` its value. This isn't allowed in Java.

```
int hexCharacter = (char)Integer.parseInt(letter,16);
```

should be

```
int hexCharacter = Integer.parseInt(letter,16);
```

Putting`(typename)` before any object or primitive casts it to be an object of type `typename`. This led to you doing an `int = char` assignment.

Comment: Wow I completely overlooked my casting. Thanks for your help!